# select positional argument in xargs

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to open the location where python is installed. To check the location I used.

```
whereis python | xargs -n 1 echo
```

output :

```
/usr/bin/python3.8

/usr/bin/python3.8-config

/usr/bin/python

/usr/lib/python2.7

/usr/lib/python3.8

/usr/lib/python3.9

/etc/python3.8

/usr/local/lib/python3.8

/usr/include/python3.8
```

Although I can copy past the location for xdg but I don't want to do it. I want to use pipe operator and open the location using `xdg-open`. However, there is one problem. How do I select the argument from the list above. Suppose I want to select the 3rd location. Is there any way to do it.

I thought of following but it did not work.

```
whereis python | xargs $3 xdg-open
```

Comment: What about `which python`? That will point to the one executable. Why xdg-open? That will not be able to open a binary executable. Ultimately, what is the *real* problem you want to solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just filter the output before passing it to xargs:

```
whereis python | awk '{print $3}' | xargs xdg-open
```

That `awk` command will only print the 3rd word, so that's all you will pass to `xargs`. Of course, using `xargs` is pointless when you just have a single argument. Perhaps you want this instead?

```
xdg-open $(whereis python | awk '{print $3}')
```

Or, simply use `which` which will return the *first* occurrence of the search string in your `$PATH`:

```
xdg-open $(which python)
```

Note that you cannot open `python` with `xdg-open`, that's nonsensical since there is no graphical program that can usefully open a binary, let alone a binary that is a scripting language.

Comment: `awk '{print $3}'` will print the third _field_ (usually "word"), not _line_. It just happens that whereis returns a list separated by spaces (which the OP broke into lines with xargs + echo) and thus this works.

Comment: @Ángel yes indeed. See [the edit history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1340996/revisions) :)  I had misunderstood the output originally and was using `awk 'NR==3'`. I fixed that in response to a comment but forgot to update the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do it *in xargs* - but you could do it with a shell:

```
whereis python | xargs sh -c 'echo "$3"' sh
```

However your particular use case doesn't really make sense, as [pointed out by vanadium](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1340982/select-positional-argument-in-xargs-bash-command#comment2290467_1340982)

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of xargs is to give every item of input to a command repeatedly.  It does not "select" from the inputs.   If you want to do that, you should use other tools like head, tail, grep.  For example:

```
whereis python | fmt -1 | tail -n +3 | head -1
```